# Disabling a particular time slot in Vaadin Calendar

Tags: java, vaadin

I am developing an application in Java Vaadin framework in which I am using its Calander Add-on. Now I want to disable a particular time slot in that calander. For example, I want that user cannot select a time slot from 4 pm to 6 pm, so the time slot of 4pm to 6pm should be shown disabled on the calander.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think disabling is directly possible, so you should probably use a workaround. You could create an "Disabled" event and use CSS class name to style that differently from reserved times. Additionally you should probably implement EventResizeHandler, EventMoveHandler and DateClickHandler defined in CalendarComponentEvents to cancel all events that overlap with reserved time slots.